# Parse can't access information for other user pointer

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

There is an object **Post** which holds a user pointer in my project. But I can't get information for other user (it's ok for my logged in user).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
  var defer = $q.defer();
  var Post = Parse.Object.extend('Post');
  var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
  query.descending('updatedAt');
  query.find({
    success : function(results) {
      var all = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var object = results[i];
        var user   = object.get('user');
        var post = {
          id          : object.id,
          nickname    : user.get('nickname'),
          image       : object.get('image'),
          thumbnail   : object.get('thumbnail'),
        };
        all.push(post);
      }
      defer.resolve(all);
    },
    error : function(error) {
      defer.reject(error.message);
    }
  });
  return defer.promise;
```

All **user** objects are fine. But I can only access the information for my logged in user. They are all undefined for the other users. For example, **user.get('nickname')** return null for users other than the logged in user.

My class level security:

[image]

And ACL for one of the user (the others are the same):

[image]

Can anybody advise what could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You need to include the pointer value in your query.. like this `query.include("user")`